# Serverless interlambda local communication

Tags: serverless, serverless-offline

I have a serverless project with 3 "layers" - `api`, `services` and `db`. Each layer is just a set of function deployed individually (I have setting  `package.individually === true` in `.serverless.yml`). All layers able to communicate using invocation mechanism from the top (api) to the bottom (db). Only `api` layer has API Gateway URL, all functions in other layers do not need to be exposed by API url.

Now project grow and we have more developers. I want to prevent issues when somebody uses `const accountDb = require('../db/account')` in, say, `api` modules (`api` must call `db` layer only through invocation wrapper).

I'd like to split single serverless project to 3 different projects but stuck on local running. I can run they locally on different ports but unable to invoke lambdas in `db` project from `api` one. It is clear why.

Question: is it possible to call one lambda in project1 from lambda in project2 while both running locally without exposing API url (I know that I can call it by AJAX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely! You'll need to used the [aws-sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/) in your project to make the lambda-to-lambda call both locally and in AWS. You'll then need to use [serverless-offline-lambda-invoke](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline-lambda-invoke) to make the call work offline (note the `endpoint` configuration option which you'll need to set locally).